# How to remove an element from InfoPath XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, infopath

I have the standard XML form and am having problems removing an element.  XML

```
<my:myFields>
    <my:Attachment>some values</my:Attachment>
</my:myFields>
```

I have tried using this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attachment"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace for 'my' needs to be specified in the XSLT.

Example,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="whatever the namespace is">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="my:Attachment"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```